# how can I reflect classes in a springboot jar's BOOT-INF/classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, classloader

I need to read a Spring Boot jar and load all the clases on a ClassLoader.

My problem,in spring boot classes are on "/BOOT-INF/classes" directory and not on the root directory.

Anybody knows how i can load this classes in my ClassLoader?

to load the classes inside /BOOT-INF/classes,no the root jar 'org.springframework.*'

Comment: Spring Boot’s launcher creates such a class loader for you. Why do you need to create your own? What do you want to use it for?

Comment: I want to scan classes in the spring-boot/BOOT-INF/classes and get the classes which used annotation "Test"

Comment: Rather than rolling your own ClassLoader, I'd use Spring Framework's built-in support for scanning the classpath and examining annotation metadata to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As Javassist only looks up classes from the class path and Spring Boot uses its own class loader hierarchy when bundling it in a self-executable. If you want to perform bytecode analysis on springboot user classes then only way is to extract the springboot jar and add each and every class to the classPath so that javassist can perform bytecode analysis on it.